# WebView2 remove space (toolbar) above PDF

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf, microsoft-edge, webview2

I am loading PDF in WebView2 control, here is my code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core

Public Class Form1
  Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    AddHandler webView.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted, AddressOf WebView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted
    AddHandler webView.NavigationCompleted, AddressOf WebView_NavigationCompleted

    Await InitializeAsync()

  End Sub

  Private Sub WebView_NavigationCompleted(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs)

  End Sub

  Private Async Function InitializeAsync() As Task
    Await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(Nothing)
    webView.Source = New Uri("file:///D:/123.pdf")
  End Function

  Private Sub WebView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs)

    webView.CoreWebView2.Settings.HiddenPdfToolbarItems = CoreWebView2PdfToolbarItems.None

  End Sub

End Class
```

Now I want to remove the black space (toolbar) that is above that PDF, look:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a winforms project, but based on your screenshots, I think you may have the webView2 control set up incorrectly, something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n68yk.png), the issue you mentioned  occurs when the WebView2 control does not tile the entire window.

So you need to confirm the size of the WebView2 control and how it will appear in the entire window, like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, the form was too small to display the actual toolbar.  Anyway, I guess that it can't be removed so I dropped this idea and disable the whole form instead (so the user won't be able to mess with that toolbar). Thanks!